# How to get every n from a number based on a known value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The title might be a bit confusing, here is want i want to accomplish.

giving `n = 51` & `m = 24` i want to get:

```
[
    {start:0, end:24}, 
    {start:24, end:48}, 
    {start:48, end:51}
]
```

so far i have this, but i need to offset the `j` and `end`

```js
var n = 51;
var m = 24;
var arr = [];    

for (var j = 0; j < n; j += m) {
  var end = (j + j) >= n ? n : j;

  console.log(j, end);

  if (j > 0) arr.push({
    start: j,
    end: end
  });
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: `a` is undefined - that's an idea

Comment: @JaromandaX my bad, forgot some code

Comment: `var end = (j + m) >= n ? n : (j + m);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `end` calculation, if `j+ m` is greater than `n` then you want `end` to be `n`

```js
var n = 51;
var m = 24;
var arr = [];

for (var j = 0; j < n; j += m) {
  var end = (j + m);

  arr.push({
    start: j,
    end: end > n ? n : end
  });
}

result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var n = 51;
var m = 21;
var arr = [];

for (var j = 0; j < n; j += m) {

  var end = j + m > n ? n : j + m;

  arr.push({
    start: j,
    end: end
  });

}

alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```